# How do you get a point (x and y coordinates) from the user using a void function?

Tags: c

I have an assignment where you need to get two points (an x and a y coordinate for each point) from the user using a void function... I'm rather new to coding so I'm not sure how to do this. I can get the coordinates from one point with a void function but I'm not sure how to get two points with one function.

Code for getting one point:

```
    void getPoint(double Ax, double Ay) {
        printf("Enter in your x coordinate: \n");
        scanf("%lf",&Ax);
        printf("Enter in your y coordinate: \n");
        scanf("%lf",&Ay);
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code of how you get one point with a void function. Getting user input should have nothing to do with the return value of a function. So we need the code to understand better what you are referring to.

Comment: Ok I added in the code for one point is that better...?

Comment: Call the function twice? Or Add two more parameters to the function?

Answer (score 1):

A `void` function will not return anything but it can modify the memory. Instead of calling the `getPoint` function with two double argument change it so it takes two pointers as arguments instead. The pointers will then point to the variable in memory which the function can modify and its value will be *returned* to the caller. This is how the `scanf` function you are using is working.

The `getPoint` function could be rewritten as

```
void getPoint(double *Ax, double *Ay) {
        printf("Enter in your x coordinate: \n");
        scanf("%lf",Ax);
        printf("Enter in your y coordinate: \n");
        scanf("%lf",Ay);
}
```

The arguments are changed from call by value to a call by reference using  two pointers to `double`.
and call it from main like this:

```
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

int main(){
   struct Point p1 = {10,20};
   struct Point p2 = {200,400};
   {
       /* data */
   };

   getPoint(&p1.x, &p1.y);
   getPoint(&p2.x, &p2.y);
}
```

This can then be refined even further as https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275403/391691 describes by replacing the `double *` with a pointer to the `struct Point`

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

void getTwoPoints(struct Point *p_point1, struct Point *p_point2) {
   printf("Enter in your x coordinate for first point: \n");
   scanf("%lf",&p_point1->x);
   printf("Enter in your y coordinate for first point: \n");
   scanf("%lf",&p_point1->y);

   printf("Enter in your x coordinate for second point: \n");
   scanf("%lf",&p_point2->x);
   printf("Enter in your y coordinate for second point: \n");
   scanf("%lf",&p_point2->y);
}

int main() {
    struct Point point1, point2;

    getTwoPoints(&point1, &point2);

    // Do whatever you want to do
    return 0;
}
```